# Projection matrix for the projection onto the nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, projection-matrices

> Find the projection matrix for the projection onto the null space of $$A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\ 2&4&6\\ -1&-2&-3\end{pmatrix}$$

I know the formula to find the projection is $$A\,(A^T\, A)^{-1}\, A^T$$

I'm having trouble getting started. There is a hint in the homework that there will be $2$ columns instead of $3$. How is that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "A" in the formula for the projection matrix needs to be a matrix whose columns form a basis for the space in question. In particular, the $A$ that you are given is **not** the $A$ that you should plug into the formula.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but how would I found the A that I should plug into the formula?

Comment: The columns should be a basis for the null space. So, find a basis for the null space.

Comment: You could also try finding the orthogonal complement of the null space, which you might be able to do by inspection. Then use the fact that the projection you’re looking for is related in a simple way to the projection onto *that* space. The result is the same, but in this case the calculation is somewhat simpler than blindly applying the formula you’ve cited.